# VBA - Dumping arrays in interspersed columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

New to VBA, I'm trying to create a report by dumping 3 different arrays into a single row in an interspersed way. By thi I mean I would like to do the following:

Arr1 (A, B, C, D, E)
Arr2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Arr3 (q, w, x, y, z)

In report:

Dynamic Range1: (A, 1, q, B, 2, w, C, 3, x, D, 4, y, E, 5, z)

Is this doable?

So far i've come wioth the following code, however it doesn't keep the order that I'¿m looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated! (:

```
Sub GETDATA(ws As Worksheet)

Dim PARRAYT() As Variant
Dim QARRAYT() As Variant
Dim DARRAYT() As Variant
'''''

'----------------
'PRICE ARRAY
'----------------


Dim PARRAY() As Variant
Dim Pws As Worksheet, Pi%, Pmsg$
ReDim PARRAY(0 To 0)

For Each Pws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Pws.Activate
    
    If Pws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If Len(PARRAY(0)) = 0 Then
            PARRAY(0) = Cells.Find(What:="Sub Total*:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Value
          Else
            ReDim Preserve PARRAY(0 To UBound(PARRAY) + 1)
             PARRAY(UBound(PARRAY)) = Cells.Find(What:="Sub Total*:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Value
        
                
          End If
    End If
Next Pws

'Message for Price Array
Pmsg = ""
For Pi = LBound(PARRAY) To UBound(PARRAY)
    Pmsg = Pmsg & Pi + 1 & ". " & PARRAY(Pi) & vbCrLf
Next Pi
MsgBox "Visible prices in array:" & vbCrLf & Pmsg, , "Array of prices"


'----------------
'DESCRIPTION ARRAY
'----------------

Dim DARRAY() As Variant
Dim Dws As Worksheet, Di%, Dmsg$
ReDim DARRAY(0 To 0)

For Each Dws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dws.Activate
    
    If Dws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If Len(DARRAY(0)) = 0 Then
            DARRAY(0) = Cells.Find(What:="SKU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, -2).Value
            
          Else
            ReDim Preserve DARRAY(0 To UBound(DARRAY) + 1)
            DARRAY(UBound(DARRAY)) = Cells.Find(What:="SKU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, -2).Value
                
                 
          End If
        End If
        
'Mesage for Desciption array
Next Dws
Dmsg = ""
For Di = LBound(DARRAY) To UBound(DARRAY)
    Dmsg = Dmsg & Di + 1 & ". " & DARRAY(Di) & vbCrLf
Next Di
MsgBox "Visible  descriptions in DARRAY:" & vbCrLf & Dmsg, , "DARRAY of descriptions"

'----------------
'QUOTE ARRAY
'----------------

Dim QARRAY() As Variant
Dim Qws As Worksheet, Qi, Qmsg
ReDim QARRAY(0 To 0)

For Each Qws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Qws.Activate
    
    If Qws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If Len(QARRAY(0)) = 0 Then
            QARRAY(0) = Cells.Find(What:="SKU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(-7, 2).Value
                QARRAY(UBound(QARRAY)) = Right((QARRAY(UBound(QARRAY))), 8)
          Else
            ReDim Preserve QARRAY(0 To UBound(QARRAY) + 1)
            QARRAY(UBound(QARRAY)) = Cells.Find(What:="SKU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(-7, 2).Value
                QARRAY(UBound(QARRAY)) = Right((QARRAY(UBound(QARRAY))), 8)
        
          End If
        End If

'Message for Quote Array
Next Qws
Dmsg = ""
For Qi = LBound(QARRAY) To UBound(QARRAY)
    Qmsg = Qmsg & Qi + 1 & ". " & QARRAY(Qi) & vbCrLf
Next Qi
MsgBox "Visible quotes in QARRAY:" & vbCrLf & Qmsg, , "QARRAY of quotes"""

''''''''''''''''''''''''
'LOGS ARRAY INTO QLOGS
'''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim Rbase As Range
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
'Rdest is the range the arrays will be dumped into
Dim Rdest As Range

LQ = LBound(QARRAY)
UQ = UBound(QARRAY)

Set wsDest = Workbooks("TrackerACG.xlsm").Sheets("QLogs")
DestLR = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Set Rbase = wsDest.Range("N" & DestLR)

'This works, kinda:
 
Set Rdest = Rbase.Resize(1, UQ + 1)
For i = 1 To UQ
Rdest.Value = QARRAY
Rdest.Offset(0, UQ + 1).Value = DARRAY
Rdest.Offset(0, UQ + UQ + 2).Value = PARRAY
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next dumping way. If you want returning array content to be dropped in the first row of the active sheet, **please, check if it is empty**. If so, you should uncomment the last code line:

```
Sub dumpingArrays()
 Dim Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, arrDmp, i As Long, k As Long

 Arr1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
 Arr2 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 Arr3 = Array("Q", "w", "X", "Y", "Z")
 
 ReDim arrDmp(UBound(Arr1) + UBound(Arr2) + UBound(Arr3) + 2)
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(Arr1)
    arrDmp(k) = Arr1(i): k = k + 1
    arrDmp(k) = Arr2(i): k = k + 1
    arrDmp(k) = Arr3(i): k = k + 1
 Next i
 
 Debug.Print Join(arrDmp, "|")
 
 'If the active sheet has its first row empty, please uncomment the next code line,
 'to drop the dumped array content:

 'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrDmp) + 1).Value = arrDmp
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...